# How to provide type-saferty for the objects with many properties in TypeScript without type annotation omitting?

Tags: typescript

My issue [`AsValue` utility type feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41356) in TypeScript repository has been declined and Nov 2020. I expected the below API:

```js
const MarkupPreprocessingDefaultSettings: AsValue = {
  mustExecuteCodeQualityInspection: true,
  waitingForOtherFilesWillBeSavedPeriod__milliseconds: 1000,
  entryPointsGroupDependent: {
    indentationSpacesCountInOutputCode: 2,
    mustExecuteHTML5_Validation: true,
    mustExecuteAccessibilityInspection: true
  }
};

// Same as
const MarkupPreprocessingDefaultSettings: {
  mustExecuteCodeQualityInspection: true,
  waitingForOtherFilesWillBeSavedPeriod__milliseconds: 1000,
  entryPointsGroupDependent: {
    indentationSpacesCountInOutputCode: 2,
    mustExecuteHTML5_Validation: true,
    mustExecuteAccessibilityInspection: true
  }
} = {
  mustExecuteCodeQualityInspection: true,
  waitingForOtherFilesWillBeSavedPeriod__milliseconds: 1000,
  entryPointsGroupDependent: {
    indentationSpacesCountInOutputCode: 2,
    mustExecuteHTML5_Validation: true,
    mustExecuteAccessibilityInspection: true
  }
};
```

O'K, but what we have instead in reality?
Let's consider the concrete problem.

### Targets

Annotate the `routing` variable such as:

1. TypeScript must to know which properties are exists, and which are no. For example, `routing.products` must work, but `routing.gibberish` must cast the TypeScript error.
2. The count of keys in addition to `products` and `orders` could be arbitrary large.
3. None of type annotating omitting, `any` and `object` allowed.

```js
type Route = {
    URN: string;
}

const routing /* : ??? */ = {
    products: {
        URN: "/products"
    },
    orders: {
        URN: "/orders"
    }
}
```

### Option 1: Annotate everything manually (overkill)

```
const routing : {
    products: Route;
    orders: Route;
    // and several thousands of keys for real commercial application ...
} = {
    products: {
        URN: "/products"
    },
    orders: {
        URN: "/orders"
    },
    // and several thousands of keys for real commercial application ...
}
```

Conclusion: non-technological, hard to extend and maintenance. Unacceptable.

### Option 2: Use indexed type (loose type saferty)

```
type Route = {
    URN: string;
}

const Routing: { [routeName: string]: Route  } = {
    products: {
        URN: "/products"
    },
    orders: {
        URN: "/orders"
    }
}

console.log(Routing.products)
console.log(Routing.orders)
console.log(Routing.gibberish) // Undefined!
```

Conclusion: it will not prevent the typo; no autocomplete available. Unacceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific question is. If the question is 'is there a better way to do this?' then I haven't yet found a perfect solution. Personally in projects I tend to put up with the found issues, but it is just the balance Typescript produces, more boilerplate for typesafety. Another option that may be worth considering in your case is to label it as 'any' and continue on your way without the typesafety. Increases risk of issues, but in some cases (and time/cost budgets) it may be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 3: Use a generic helper function

```
const asRouting = <T extends Record<keyof T, Route>>(t: T) => t;

const routing = asRouting({
   products: {
      URN: "/products"
   },
   orders: {
      URN: "/orders"
   }
});
```

If you annotate the `routing` variable at all, the compiler will treat the variable as being of the annotated type only, and you won't get any type inference.  As you see, either you have to annotate with exactly the right type, which is redundant, *or* you annotate a type which is wider than you want, and you lose type information you care about.  So you really shouldn't annotate `routing`. Let the compiler infer its type for you.

But what if you mistakenly initialize `routing` with a value where one or more of the properties is not a valid `Route`?  Well, the code that uses `routing` will yield a compiler error. But that is likely to be quite far from the definition of `routing`.  You'd like the compiler error to be right there so you can fix it.

That's where the generic helper function above comes in.  `asRouting()` is an identity function at runtime, and just outputs the same value as the input.  At compile time, it is also an identity function, and the output type will be the same as the input type.  But since this type, `T`, is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, Route>`, `asRouting()` will only accept inputs where all its properties are valid `Route` objects.

Let's see what happens with `routing` as defined above.  Its inferred type can be shown via IntelliSense to be:

```
/* const routing: {
    products: {
        URN: string;
    };
    orders: {
        URN: string;
    };
} */
```

Which is exactly the type you want, without requiring that you spell it out:

```
console.log(routing.products.URN); // okay
console.log(routing.orders.URN); // okay
console.log(routing.somethingElse); // compiler error!
// ---------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'somethingElse' does not exist
```

But you still get all the type checking you need to ensure that all properties are `Route`:

```
const badRouting = asRouting({
   products: {
      URL: "/product"; // error! 
   // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
   //  Object literal may only specify known properties, 
   //  and 'URL' does not exist in type 'Route'
   }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gKCjgqjAOQC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG5MBfTTAYzhvKgENT4SWnShoAPABUoEAB7IaAE1KwInCgrEBrCCDgAzKBIA0sRMgB85gBTASEgJSjzUYEw5ceFM8NF8B3+issHCgwLwUEdmBSEmCQvEISACIAejC4CKjSJOwcZiNcqDh1CAoYjEKQ-GIoVOKFUuyoQtZmeyYUgCooTm5gKC8heljK9Mzokfj46pJyanomeOZFkPrGyamEmrnhFbymZihOlLZe0jgAGwgAOgu4OitB4GFrscjo6+r2qBSUos1eCB3NxLjc7g8ni81mVPoRvr9-oDgecrrd7o8AnRrucALYQYAAC2EAFELqQIPC-pwcWAqFcKNIKF4KABCTAIgC0XO5PN5zgAfoKhcKhey-gAFLyQCigKAAclx+KJ9FJ5LlUAUcAgyhocH6sio5DYyP6ACNeApBM96L5+FbhEFCm8shtpjAADLJNLhd5JBg-P6lZks5ohBEiiMi0M4BFQADypoAVqp+hcqMgKLwLlAcYCijQLiAyJB2FQ9EXNLqAO40UJS0rPbUmQqx3iKeX4d3qzXaqC6-UyQ39WgucDQOVWiBylosexAA)

Comment: Thank you for answer! Would you please to say which type will be in `XXX` position of `const routing: XXX: asRouting({ /* */ })`?

Comment: It is of type `Record<"products" | "orders", Route>` but you wouldn't want to manually annotate it as such.

Comment: I know that TypeScript development team does not approve the "100% of types must be annotated" approach, but I am adhering it because of human psychology reasons. However, I'll refrain from dispute should I do it or no.